# How to pass list argument to vertex AI with gcloud cli for custom training job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

How can I pass the **list argument** to vertex AI with `gcloud cli` when creating custom training?

I am using [`gcloud ai custom-jobs create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/custom-jobs/create) command to [create custom training job](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/create-custom-job).

When using [gcloud CLI of AI platform](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform), it was simply like the below and didn't need to escape anything. However, in vertex AI the following error occurs when passing the list argument.

###### gcloud CLI (AI platform)

> gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training {JOB_ID}} 
> ... 
> --info-columns=['column_01','column_02'] 
> ...

###### gcloud CLI (Vertex AI)

```bash
gcloud ai custom-jobs create \
    --region us-central1 \
    --display-name=[DISPLAY_NAME] \
    --project=[PROJECT] \
    --python-package-uris='[BUCKET_URI]/trainer-0.1.tar.gz' \
    --worker-pool-spec=machine-type=e2-standard-4,replica-count=1,executor-image-uri='us-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/training/tf-cpu.2-11:latest',python-module=trainer.task \
    --args=--sample-int=100 \
    --args=--sample-string=12 \
    --args=--sample-bool=True \
    --args=--sample-columns=['column_01','column_02','column_03']
    # --args=--sample-columns="['column_01','column_02','column_03']"  # tried
    # --args=--sample-columns=['column_01'\,'column_02'\,'column_03']  # tried
```

###### Error:

[image]

###### inside `trainer/task.py`

```py
import argparse, ast

def parse_arguments():
    def str2bool(v):
        if isinstance(v, bool):
            return v
        elif v.lower() in ('true', 't'):
            return True
        elif v.lower() in ('false'):
            return False

    def str2list(s):
        v = ast.literal_eval(s)
        return v

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--sample-int', type=int, default=5)
    parser.add_argument('--sample-string', type=str, required=False)
    parser.add_argument('--sample-bool', type=str2bool, required=False)
    parser.add_argument('--sample-columns', type=str2list, default=['column_01', 'column_02'])
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
```

I am expecting something like escaping command like [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping), but couldn't find one for Vertex AI. I have checked [[post_01]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69622827/gcp-dataflow-pass-list-as-argument),
[[post_02]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73830357/issues-with-passing-command-line-args-to-custom-training-job-vertex-ai), but I couldn't find a similar case.

Comment: I end up using passing `^` separated string and paring the string with `^` as eliminator rather than `,`. However, I still want to know if there is a correct way other than this bypass method.

Comment: If you know the answer later, please reply here.